# How can I load a resource bundle properties file within a composite component?

Tags: jsf, composite-component, resourcebundle, properties-file

My component library directory tree is setup as the following:

```
resources
    mylib
        css
            mycomponent.css
        properties
            mycomponent.properties
        mycomponent.xhtml
```

I'd like to load the properties file within mycomponent.xhtml to use for messages.  What is the proper way of doing this?  Is there an f:loadbundle type of solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composites have implicit support for resource bundles via [`#{cc.resourceBundleMap}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getResourceBundleMap()). This only prerequires:

- Bundle file is placed in same (sub)folder as composite XHTML itself.
- Bundle file has exactly the same filename (prefix) as composite XHTML itself.

So, if you restructure a bit,

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- mylib
 |         |-- mycomponent.css
 |         |-- mycomponent.properties
 |         `-- mycomponent.xhtml
 :
```

Then you should be able to access it as below:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="mylib" name="mycomponent.css" />
    ...
    <p>Property with key "foo": #{cc.resourceBundleMap.foo}</p>
    <p>Property with key "foo.bar": #{cc.resourceBundleMap['foo.bar']}</p>
</cc:implementation>
```